# Почему не работает ng-show?

Tags: angularjs

На странице есть элемент заведомо с `display:none`.

Когда в Angular JS получаю ответ от аякса - элемент должен появляться. Но этого не происходит:

```
ng-show="globalSearch.data.length"
```

Значение больше 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngShow/ngHide` для скрытия добавляет класс `ng-hide`, для показа - убирает этот класс.Этот класс имеет правило `display:none !important`. 
Вам необходимо в своих стилях для элемент убрать `display:none` и добавить класс для элемента класс `ng-hide`.

Answer (score 1):

В Ng директивах должно стоять выражение:

```
ng-show="globalSearch.data.length>0"
```